How to reinstall broken kernel, Ubuntu 22.04?
I wanted to install drivers for the Wifi module. Because Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't see the WiFi module.
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git - I used this one. And used make install here.
After rebooting the system was broken. Nothing worked even the command line.
Then I used the LiveCD to update grub to get the recovery menu.
And I have the following kernels:
dpkg --list | grep linux-image

ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1026-intel-iotg   5.15.0-1026.31   amd64   Signed kernel image intel-iotg
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1063-intel-iotg   5.15.0-1063.69   amd64   Signed kernel image intel-iotg
ii  linux-image-intel-iotg               5.15.0.1063.63   amd64   Intel-Iotg Linux kernel image

When I select linux-image-5.15.0-1026 - it works. Ubuntu loads and everything works fine. But when I select linux-image-5.15.0-1063 - nothing works.
I tried to reinstall it:
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-1063-intel-iotg

But it didn't help as well. I tried to fix it via the recovery menu but the results are the same.
It may be a simple solution, but I can't find it. Could you please help to handle it? How can I restore or reinstall the kernel?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I tried to reinstall kernel in such way:
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.15.0-1063-intel-iotg
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-5.15.0-1063-intel-iotg
reboot

Then the system loads with linux-image-5.15.0-1026 by default - and it works correctly. Then I wanted to reinstall the kernel linux-image-5.15.0-1063
sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-1063-intel-iotg
reboot

It became a bit better but anyway there are some kernel issues. And
I don't know how to fix them.
Any ideas? What did I wrong?

Welcome! Kernel 5.15 doesn't work on my system as well, I use hwe one , 6.8.
